# How to add a user to a private channel by discord bot code in node and javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to add a user of the server to the channel once they verify there email id. Once they are verified they should be added to a private channel which already exists of discord server. However I am new here and not able to find what to do here. My code is as below:

```js
      client.on('message',(message)=>{
       if(message.content=="!join-clan1"){
            if (message.author.bot) return;
            message.reply("Check your DM please");
            message.author.send("Enter your email Id please? you have some time").then((newmsg)=>{
                newmsg.channel.awaitMessages(response => response.content,{
                    max:1,
                    time:500000,
                    errors:['time'],
                }).then((collected)=>{
                    newmsg.channel.send(`Email id is : ${collected.first().content}`);
                    if(collected.first().content == "DATABASE ID OF MEMBER"){
                   //COde here to add the member to private channel
                    }
                })
            });
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured out an another way. It is simply to give a role in your private channel. The way to do it is simply this

```
let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "Normal User");
                let member = message.member;
                member.roles.add(role).catch(console.error);
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

First, you'd have to get the voice channel, like:

```
const myChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.get('id-here');
```

Then, assuming the default permission for @everyone is view_channel: false and send_messages: false, you can do this to allow the member to see it:

```
myChannel.updateOverwrite(message.member, {
    SEND_MESSAGES: true,
    VIEW_CHANNEL: true
});
```

Comment: It is a text channel. I guess text should work!

Comment: @COdeingNinja sorry I misunderstood your question, I thought you were talking about voice. I have edited the question to show how to edit permissions for a text channel.

Comment: `updateOverwrite` has been removed in v13 of discord.js, and replaced with `permissionOverwrites` - see https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#guildchannel